# How can I concatenate file path?

Tags: c++, file, char, concatenation, sdl

I need only concatenate a file path, in C++ using library SDL Mixer 2.0:

something like this:

```
#include<SDL2/SDL_mixer.h>

string myColor = "red";

sound = Mix_LoadWAV("D:\\car"+myColor+".wav"); //or this
sound = Mix_LoadWAV("D:\\car"+"red"+".wav");
// is generate a error:

#define Mix_LoadWAV(file)
```

Comment: myColor in `Mix_LoadWAV()` shouldn't be in quotes, as you are trying to pass a variable, not a string

Comment: oh, I already tried this too...
I messed up typing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Mix_LoadWAV](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/docs/SDL_mixer_19.html) receives a `char *file` so you'll need to convert from `std::string` to `char*`

```
sound = Mix_LoadWAV(("D:\\car" + myColor + ".wav").c_str());
```

Comment: Man, big big Thanks!!! I was sucess with other, but this is very simple and works fine!!!! Thank you so much!!!